# javascript String.split not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser

i am trying to split a string in javascript . it works fine in firefox but, it fails in chrome. could anyone please share the ideas in this.

i used the following code:

```
var v="asd.sdf";
var arr=v.split('.');
```

Comment: Works for me. Tried `'arr.arr2'.split('.')` and got `["arr", "arr2"]` in the console of Chrome 17.0.963.78. The problem must be somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it in Chrome 17.0.963.78 and it works fine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var str="asd.sdf";
var arr = str.split(".");
document.write(arr);
document.write("<br />DONE<br />");
document.write(str.split(".") + "<br />");


</script>
```

Gave:

```
asd,sdf
DONE
asd,sdf
```

What am I doing that is different to you?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of bug is most often some other code in that session corrupting the global String objects split function.

Try the same code in a very basic web page with no other javascript.

If it still doesn't work It is possible that this can be caused by dodgy plugins, so try disabling any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced this problem on chrome. After some couple of page refreshing the problem disappeared.